# Where is this Android Wear app?

Tags: android, sony-smartwatch, wear-os

I want to start developing apps on my smart watch, but i can't get the app to connect to my phone. I got stuck on even the first line:

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html#SetupDevice

where it says `Install the Android Wear app, available on Google Play, on your handheld.`... i've tried on my nexus 4 and couldn't find the Android Wear app for my life. Then i tried a Samsung S4 and it's the same story. Where is this mysterious `Android Wear` app?

Comment: Apps also appear to have been removed http://www.techtimes.com/articles/9472/20140702/android-wear-apps-appear-on-google-play-store-or-not.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have followed the instructions here http://developer.android.com/preview/google-play-services-wear.html to get the latest version of Google Play Services. You need to opt-in and then download the latest versions of all three packages (Google Play Services, Google Search, Android Wear Companion) in the provided order for this to work properly. These steps are only necessary while Google Play Services is rolling out, and in a few weeks will become unnecessary.

Comment: The Google Play Services 5.0 rollout has completed http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/07/google-play-services-5.html, so these instructions will no longer be needed. The Android Wear app is now visible in the Play Store at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.wearable.app